# IE adding pixels to width

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm making a site and on some pages IE is adding some pixels to make it have a horizontal scroll bar and on others it is not.  I really can't figure out what is wrong here.  Here is my CSS any help will be greatly appreciated (I'm using jQuery on the site if that effects your answer any).

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:900px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;                
}
.north {
    height: 100px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.south {
    height: 2em;
    background-color: #3F3F3F;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    font-size:80%;
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    width:100%;
    display:block !important;
    position:absolute !important;
    bottom:0px !important;
    left:0px !important;
}
.west {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 0.78em;
}
.center {
    font-size: 80%;
    height:auto;
    min-width:300px;
}
```

Those multiple !important notation where a fix for some other stuff what wasn't working, but removing them doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Show the relevant html please.

Comment: or a link to the site, please.

Comment: please do, so that we could help

Comment: The page requires a login to function properly, and the site isn't released to the public yet.

Comment: Extract the relevant bits of HTML and put it, any relevant javascript and CSS on www.jsfiddle.net then people can see it and play with it (once you give us the relevant JSFIDDLE webpage address) to figure what is wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jefffan24/3pjNS/2/  ....I can't get it to look right on jsFiddle but that is the code.  The CSS controls the whole page basically so the relevant css, js and html is the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely margin in North.  IE's box model is different from all other browsers.  Try commenting that (and any other container padding & margin) and see if that solves the issue.

Also what's in the container might be blowing it up.  IE doesn't respect widths and will expand the container to support the contents whereas other browsers won't.  You can see if this is the case by adding "overflow: hidden" to the elements.

Also, learn to use your tools.  Use the IE Developer tools (hit F12 in IE8) and then use the select by click (looks like a box with the pointer in it on the tool's toolbar) to put a border on the elements to see which one is the culprit.

Comment: IE's box model is not different from other browsers, unless you put IE into quirks mode.

Comment: True, but if there's no doctype quirks mode is activated ("Additionally, a web page which does not include a DOCTYPE at all will render in quirks mode." from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Comment: When I did F12 in IE, and I went to where it shows the box layout with a graphic.  It is showing the width as 1920 (my screen size) but I have a vertical scroll bar and I think that is the problem. It is trying to make the page the width of the screen when it really needs to do it the width of the screen - the width of the scroll bar.  Now I can't get rid of the vertical scroll bar, is there anyway I can fix this.  Also like I said it is only happening on some pages, the other pages have scroll bars too but its not doing it on them.